# Autocomplete Material UI: Cant hide selected option in input when multiple={false}

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

With `renderTags={() => null}`, I can disable to render the selected options in the InputField. This doesn't work with `multiple={false}`. Does anyone have a solution and knows why that is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that prop is specifically for `multiple` you can review the source code for `Autocomplete` here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/9691ba77f3e27193c9cbff77ff85caaca22706b5/packages/material-ui/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js

Pay attention to the condition statement below. It checks to see if `multiple` is `true` and if `value.length > 0` (additional check if `value` array contains at least 1 element).

Although it does not explicitly state it in the documentation, from the prop name itself "`renderTags`" - these are the "tags" that you see when multiple selection is enabled.

```
if (multiple && value.length > 0) {
  const getCustomizedTagProps = (params) => ({
    className: clsx(classes.tag, {
      [classes.tagSizeSmall]: size === 'small',
    }),
    disabled,
    ...getTagProps(params),
  });

  if (renderTags) {
    startAdornment = renderTags(value, getCustomizedTagProps);
  } else {
    startAdornment = value.map((option, index) => (
      <Chip
        label={getOptionLabel(option)}
        size={size}
        {...getCustomizedTagProps({ index })}
        {...ChipProps}
      />
    ));
  }
}
```

I am not entirely sure why you'd want to hide the selected value on your `Autocomplete` but using CSS can do that work for you.